# Draw 0 or more cardinality relationship in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, cardinality

How to be drawn 1: 0 or more relationship in mysql workbench? I used manual assign method. I don't do just drag and match method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw any relationship and then edit it by opening the relationship editor via double click on the relationship. Then select the 1:n cardinality and uncheck "mandatory":

[image]

Of course you could also simply use the second relationship tool (hotkey: 2) to drag a 1:n relationship on the canvas.